# Efficiently storing posts inside a Collection Folder

Tags: entity-framework, mapping

I am creating a folder system in my website for Users or Admin to store posts inside them.

For reference, I am creating my website using ASP.NET Core MVC and C#. The database I am using is Microsoft SQL Server.

I have 2 database tables, `Posts` and `Collections`. `Collections` table is to be used as folder/container that anyone can create, to store any existing post.

Now my question is, should I create a `CollectionId` column *inside* `Posts` table **or** should I create `PostId` column *inside* my `Collections` table?

Here is an example:

`Posts` table

| Id | PostTitle | .. | CollectionId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Title 1 | .. | 1, 2, 4, 7 |
| 2 | Title 2 | .. | *null* |
| 3 | Title 3 | .. | 3, 1 |
| .. | .. | .. | .. |

Here, the numbers in first row `1, 2, 3, 7` are the Id of Collections the Posts are added to. The Id's are separated by commas.

**OR**

`Collections` table

| Id | CollectionName | .. | PostId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Collection 1 | .. | 1, 43, 6, 34, .. |
| 2 | Collection 2 | .. | 3, 6, 1, 45, .. |
| 3 | Collection 3 | .. | 12, 34, 44, 45, .. |
| .. | .. | .. | .. |

Here, the numbers in first row `1, 43, 6, 34, ..` are Id of Posts that are added to the Collection. The Id's are separated by commas.

Comment: If you're doing this from scratch - please **DO NOT** use a kludge like comma-separated ID's in a single column - set up a **proper** many-to-many relationship between `Posts` and `Collections` - a "join" table that contains the PK of both tables, which allows you (and Entity Framework) to nicely and properly (and without messy parsing) handle a many-to-many relationship

Comment: @marc_s If the users can Create, Edit and Delete a collection, how can a many-to-many relation be set up?

Comment: If you want to add a post to a collection (or vice-versa), just add an entry with the two relevant PK values to the join table.

Comment: Recent versions of **EF Core** will also handle this for you entirely automatically and transparently; see [EF Core many-to-many relationships](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships/many-to-many)